# How to draw graph of elliptic cylinder over (x,y) plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation of cylinder is

$ \left(x+2y\right) ^{2}+z^{2} -1=0 $.

How to make graph (as much as possible as is it) of elliptic cylinder over a plane (x,y)?

I am really confused how to represent this with only two coordinates? How is that possible?

Comment: Hint: This is similar to asking for the graph of a sphere with equation $x^2+y^2+z^2-4=0$. Do you see how a sphere has parts that are surfaces that can be graphed above some part of the $x$-$y$ plane?

Comment: No. I still dont understand.

Comment: For the sphere (and for the cylinder), you can solve for $z$ to get two functions of $f(x,y)$ to graph as surfaces. For your cylinder, $z^2=1-(x+2y)^2$, so the functions are $z=f_1(x,y)=\sqrt{1-(x+2y)^2}$ and $z=f_2(x,y)=-\sqrt{1-(x+2y)^2}$.

Comment: But if I put that in some math program I will still get 3D plot... or to use substitution for (x+2y) ?

Comment: If your program can draw 3D plots, it will work. For example, Google can: http://bit.ly/25gU5uC